# How to position a caption below a Bootstap4 basic slider

Tags: html, css, captions

I need to position a caption below a basic slider in Bootstap4. 
This is my HTML code

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5" style="float:right; padding:0;">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/1.jpg" alt="First slide">
                <div class="newcaption">
                    <p>First caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                <div class="newcaption">
                    <p>Second caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                <div class="newcaption">
                    <p>Third caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>  
</div>
```

First, my css is

```
.carousel-inner{position:relative; width:100%; overflow:hidden;}
.newcaption{position:absolute; bottom:-25px; top:auto; color:#000;}
```

Then it turn like this

> https://ibb.co/nG3rhw

(Sory, I had reputation not enough to post images.)

Then I changed overflow: "hidden" to "visible" in .carousel-inner . Now it work but it show 2 images while change image like this

> https://ibb.co/dd7v9b

**So how can I position a caption in this issue?**

Comment: can u share a jsfiddle or codepen link...it ll be helpful

Comment: if you want to position right above the carousel image then change `.newcaption{position:absolute; bottom:0; top:auto; color:#000;}` otherwise if you dont want to show it above carousel but below it it you would have to manage it out of carousel. showing captions according to the current slide'

Comment: please add jsfiddle with complete scripts.

Answer (score 1):

See css working with following code, Run code snippet and check result.

```css
.carousel-inner{position:relative; width:100%; overflow:hidden}
.newcaption{position:absolute; bottom:5px; top:auto; color:#000; left:5px}
.newcaption p{ margin:0px}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5" style="float:right; padding:0;">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://midtowncarpetcleaning.com/wp-content/themes/envision/lib/images/default-placeholder-1000x600.png" alt="First slide">
                <div class="newcaption">
                    <p>First caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://midtowncarpetcleaning.com/wp-content/themes/envision/lib/images/default-placeholder-1000x600.png" alt="First slide">
                <div class="newcaption">
                    <p>Second caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://midtowncarpetcleaning.com/wp-content/themes/envision/lib/images/default-placeholder-1000x600.png" alt="First slide">
                <div class="newcaption">
                    <p>Third caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It still can't display a caption that out of image bound.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5" style="float:right; padding:0;">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://midtowncarpetcleaning.com/wp-content/themes/envision/lib/images/default-placeholder-1000x600.png" alt="First slide">
                <div class="newcaption">
                    <p>First caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://midtowncarpetcleaning.com/wp-content/themes/envision/lib/images/default-placeholder-1000x600.png" alt="Second slide">
                <div class="newcaption">
                    <p>Second caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://midtowncarpetcleaning.com/wp-content/themes/envision/lib/images/default-placeholder-1000x600.png" alt="Third slide">
                <div class="newcaption">
                    <p>Third caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>  
</div>
<style>
.carousel-inner{position:relative; width:100%; overflow:hidden;}
.newcaption{position:absolute; bottom:2px; top:auto; color:#000; left:5px;}
.newcaption p{ margin:0px; }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```